# Tax only on item price, not on shipping price

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

[image]How can i apply tax only on Item price not on Shipping price ?
I have setup tax rate 7.25 % 
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **System > configuration > sales > tax**  & gave **Excluding Tax** for **Shipping Prices**  as below image :

[image]

Comment: I made changes as you mentioned, but not working.

Comment: @DeveloperWebile can you please clear cache once by deleting `cache` folder which is present under `var` folder..... or try flushing cache in backend.......

Comment: i tried all,
Let me explainmy scenario.
i have product worh price $22
Tax rate is $7.25, and shipping charge is $9.40.

At estimation on cart page final total is displaying $33.68

Comment: @DeveloperWebile so it should display 38.65 [ 22 + 7.25 + 9.40 ].....

Comment: I have added snapshot.

Comment: @DeveloperWebile how much shipping price you set for that `united parcel service shipping method`..... in backend.....